# How to insert php array values into chart.js line chart?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I've made this to that point:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM monitoring") or die(mysql_error());
$wartosci = array();

while ($row_danych = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $wartosci[] = $row_danych;

foreach ($wartosci as $wartosc) {
   echo "{$wartosc[temp1]}<br>"
      . "{$wartosc[temp2]}<br>"
        . "{$wartosc[wilg]}<br>"
      . "{$wartosc[swia]}<br>"
      . "{$wartosc[cisn]}<br>"
        . "{$wartosc[zan]}<br>"
      . "{$wartosc[woda]}<br><br>";
}
?>
```

And, thanks to the "echo" I get my result like this:

```
85.00
32.50
48.50
20
981.59
30
35

32.25
32.40
49.30
20
981.63
30
35

32.38
32.40
48.10
20
981.58
30
35
```

And so on. Now, how do I insert this arrays into chart.js line graph with 7 datasets? I need to insert every row separately. I've tried just:

```
data: {$wartosc[temp1]}
```

But with this, the chart disappears.

I tried also this:

```
echo json_encode($wartosc[temp1]);
```

In the foreach loop. Then in the first dataset:

```
data: <?=json_decode($wartosc[temp1]);?>
```

And the chart isn't even visible, like before.

Comment: Didn't work. I got error "unexpected echo at line xy", it worked when I removed the "=" from the statement, but still the chart doesn't work.

Comment: why you don't use `foreach` loop to echo values?

Comment: I've added to the foreach loop these statements:
    $value1 = $wartosc[temp1];
    $value1_js = json_encode($value1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

and in data I have:

    data: <?php json_decode($value1_js); ?>

But still it doesn't work
@aidin